# Collection initializers inside object initializers with default values

Tags: c#, api-design, collection-initializer, least-astonishment

I just stumbled upon the following issue:

```
class Settings
{
    // Let's set some default value: { 1 }
    public ICollection<int> AllowedIds = new List<int>() { 1 };
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var s = new Settings
    {
        AllowedIds = { 1, 2 }
    };

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", s.AllowedIds)); // prints 1, 1, 2
}
```

**I understand why this happens:** `AllowedIds = { 1, 2 }` is *not* an assignment but a *collection initializer inside an object initializer*, i.e., it's an implicit call of `AllowedIds.Add(1); AllowedIds.Add(2)`.

Still, for me it was a gotcha, since it *looks* like an assignment (since it uses `=`).

As an API/library developer (let's say I'm the one developing the `Settings` class) who wants to adhere to the [principle of least surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment), **is there anything I can do to prevent the consumers of my library from falling into that trap?**

---

Footnotes:

- In that particular case, I could use an `ISet/HashSet<int>` instead of `ICollection/List` (since duplicates do not make sense for `AllowedIds`), which would yield the expected result of `1, 2`. Still, initializing `AllowedIds = { 2 }` would yield the counter-intuitive result of `1, 2`.
- I found a related discussion on the [C# github repo](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/3430), which basically concluded that, yes, this syntax is confusing, but it's an old feature (introduced in 2006), and we can't change it without breaking backwards compatibility.

Comment: Wow. That is a surprise. I suspect other than mention it in the documentation, there's nothing much you can do about it, but then again, I might be wrong here.

Comment: That is surprising.  I've never noticed this before.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not expecting the user of the `Settings` class to *add* to `AllowedIds`, why expose it as an `ICollection<int>` (which contains an `Add` method and signifies the intention to be added into)?

The reason why `AllowedIds = { 1, 2 }` works in your code is because C# uses duck typing to [call the `Add` method on the collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers). If you eliminate the possibility of the compiler finding an `Add` method, there will be a compile error on the line `AllowedIds = { 1, 2 }`, thus preventing the trap.

You can do something like:

```cs
class Settings
{
    // Let's set some default value: { 1 }
    public IEnumerable<int> AllowedIds { get; set; } = new List<int> { 1 };
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var s = new Settings
    {
        AllowedIds = new List<int> { 1, 2 }
    };

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", s.AllowedIds)); // prints 1, 2
}
```

This way you are still allowing the caller to set a new collection using the setter, while preventing the trap you mentioned.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the Settings class no longer really controls the AllowedIds property very well.  For example, Settings may want to implement an `AddAllowedId` method.  The initial value is a list, but down in `Main`, someone could have set it to an array of int (which also implements `IEnumerable <int>`, but doesn't allow Adding.  I think Settings will need to have an IEnumerable property getter and then some code to allow adding IDs

Comment: @Flydog57 Yes. what you are describing is to make the `Settings` class immutable or have an `AddAllowedId` method for controlled mutation. However, since OP's code is already exposing `AllowedIds` as an `ICollection<int>` to begin with, i.e. they should be well aware that class is mutable, my answer is the easiest way to prevent callers from falling into the trap OP was describing.